# Populate Django Choice field from database based on user.has_perms

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to update a choice field depending on the user permissions. I have a boolean field which if False (default) the standard user gets to see. Otherwise if a user has the permission I want to display everything.

**views.py**

```
class ExportFormView(FormView):

    template_name = 'export.html'
    form_class = ExportForm
    success_url = '/'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
         kwargs = super(ExportFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
         kwargs.update({
             'request' : self.request
         })
         return kwargs
```

**forms.py**

```
class ExportForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(ExportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    choice_list = []

    if request.user.has_perms('tracker.print_all'):
        e = Muid.objects.values('batch_number').distinct()
    else:
        e = Muid.objects.values('batch_number').distinct().filter(printed=False)
    for item in e:
        choice = item['batch_number']
        choice_list.append((choice, choice))

    batch_number = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choice_list)
```

Error I get:

```
NameError at /
name 'request' is not defined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a while now (And tried many googled SO suggestions/Answers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out how to do it, still interested in other ways.

Using pdb, I found that the view was setup correctly. But I had to alter the form. I couldn't access the variable from outside of a function such as __init__, others functions should be able to access the variable too, but I needed to create the form on init, so I couldn't wait for function calls.

Code:

**Views.py**

```
class ExportFormView(FormView):

template_name = 'export_muids.html'
form_class = ExportForm
success_url = '/'

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(ExportFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({
         'request' : self.request
    })
    return kwargs
```

**forms.py**

```
class ExportForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        choice_list = []

        if request.user.has_perms('tracker.print_all'):
            e = Muid.objects.values('batch_number').distinct()
        else:
            e = Muid.objects.values('batch_number').distinct().filter(exported=False)
        for item in e:
            choice = item['batch_number']
            choice_list.append((choice, choice))
        super(ExportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['batch_number'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choice_list)
```

Comment: Another reference [http://ilian.i-n-i.org/django-forms-choicefield-with-dynamic-values/](http://ilian.i-n-i.org/django-forms-choicefield-with-dynamic-values/).